# Android browser issues HEAD request then GET, but PHP session is lost

Tags: php, android, session-variables

A PHP application loses session data only in Android browser and only when logs show a HEAD request was issued immediately prior to the GET request.

Success ... 
99.123.321.99 - - [05/Oct/2016:11:12:46 -0500] "GET /Success.php?response=Y HTTP/1.1" 200 6772

No session ... 
98.12.21.89 - - [04/Oct/2016:22:17:15 -0500] "HEAD /Success.php?response=Y HTTP/1.1" 200 -
98.12.21.89 - - [04/Oct/2016:22:17:15 -0500] "GET /Success.php?response=Y HTTP/1.1" 200 3007

User agents are comparable, except on requests which lose the session data (returning Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4) ...

99.123.321.99   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; LG-H901 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.124 Mobile Safari/537.36

98.12.21.89   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G925T Build/MMB29K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.124 Mobile Safari/537.36
98.12.21.89   Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

What causes the Android browser to act in this manner?

What steps can be taken to 'work around' the behavior (and preserve session data)?

It is likely that the application will be rewritten with application defined session data instead of relying upon native PHP sessions, but an immediate work around would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, did you come to a conclusion over why user agents with `Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)` cannot retain session data? I appear to have the same issue in my Symfony application which relies on session data which it appears this device/browser cannot retain. I haven't found anything else online to back this up other than your SO post.

Comment: @crmpicco - No, I have not found any further explanation for the behavior of the Android browser and the HEAD request immediately preceding the GET.  I found virtually nothing in my online search as well.  We modified our application to reduce reliance upon the session data.  Good luck!